# MAMP (windows) different php.ini loaded from console..why?

Tags: php, symfony, console, installation, mamp

I try to load PHP from console (in windows) and when I run phpinfo.php the line

```
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
```

but when I run this pagin in web browser I see it:

```
Loaded Configuration File   C:\MAMP\conf\php5.6.28\php.ini
```

My problem appear when I try to install symfony

```
Warning: readfile(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in Command line code on line 1

Warning: readfile(https://symfony.com/installer): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in Command line code on line 1
```

I can't able to download this file from console, can anyone help me please?

Comment: The console does not use the same PHP as the browser does. try to run `php -i` to find the information about the PHP running in your console.

Comment: I try to copy same php.ini from mamp\conf\<phpVersion>\php.ini in relative mamp\bin directory and it's work.... finally I remove MAMP!